# How to send filtered data with Ajax back to PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I implemented my Custom Post Type, and I need to filter my data based on some Taxonomy.

PHP code with data of Custom Post Type:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'studien', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' =>  intval($allItemsCount));



    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    if($loop->have_posts()):
    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();?>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="cpt-studies-block">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a class="zoom-picture-hover" href="<?php the_permalink()?>">
                        <div class="cpt-studies-block-image picture">
                            <?php $thumb_img=wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('image'),'custom-crop-studien'); ?>
                            <img class="img" src="<?php echo $thumb_img[0]; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                        <span><?php the_field('date')?></span>
                        <h3>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>">
                                <?php the_title()?>
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                        <p class="cpt-studies-block-text"><?php the_field('text')?></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" class="cpt-studies-block-link link-read-more"> <?php
                            $svg_file = 'wp-content/themes/bb_boilerplate/img/svg/icon_arrow.svg';
                            $svg_file = file_get_contents($svg_file);
                            $find_string   = '<svg';
                            $position = strpos($svg_file, $find_string);
                            $svg_file_new = substr($svg_file, $position);
                            echo $svg_file;
                            ?>
                            <?php if (get_field('button_text')):
                                the_field('button_text');
                            else : echo __('More', 'dw');?>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile;
    endif;
    ?>
```

PHP function on processing my taxonomy value...

```
$type = $_GET['type'];

$result = array();

$args = array(
        "post_type" => "studien",
        "post_per_page" => -1,
        "relation" => "AND"
);


if($type != "")
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(

        'taxonomy' => 'market',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $type
    );

$search_query = new WP_Query($args);

while($search_query->have_posts()) {

    $search_query->the_post();

    $result[] = array(
      "id" => get_the_ID(),
      "title" => get_the_title(),
      "permalink" => get_permalink(),
      "date" => get_field('date'),
      "text" => get_field('text'),
      "button_text" => get_field('button_text'),
      "button_link" => get_field('button_link'),
      "image" => get_field('image'),
      "imageSvg" => $svg_file
    );

  echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Javascript code on filtering data with custom taxonomy:

```
jQuery(function($) { // Short for jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', searchForm, function (event) {

       event.preventDefault();

       var data = {
           action: "studien_search",
           type: $("#taxonomy-market-type").val()
       };



        $.ajax({
            url : ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {

            // here send data back to PHP code above

} 
})


    });
});
```

Filtering worked pretty good, but that version proccesed and encode response in JSON and I need to send `$search_query` in AJAX function in `success()` part. Does anyone know how to do that ???

Comment: Hi @Matus, I would like to clear you that you cannot set server side variables(PHP) using javascript(client side language). To set any PHP variable you need to set it using PHP code instead of Javascript. I suggest you to render page response(HTML) on the basis of Ajax response using Javascript. Javascript or JQuery provides various methods to set value DOM elements.

Comment: So, your advice is to change structure of code and set value for DOM elements? Will I have to change my code example?

Comment: As your code states you are using AJAX just to show synchronous response to modify page HTML, in Javascript or JQuery it is possible by modifying DOM elements. So you can set DOM elements using JQuery or Javascript once you receive response in success()

Comment: And after setting DOM elements is change to send some response back to my PHP code above?? you know , due to efficiency. I tried work with $result array, but that way is not appropriate

Comment: you need to understand that using AJAX you can modify PHP variable value but that PHP variable will not show its modified value on page synchronously because PHP is server side language.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You are getting the `$result` array via JSON and now you want to send it back? Why? Usually an AJAX response is used to update the DOM.

Comment: JSON was method I implemented according tutorial, but I realized, that JSON response can´t process my php code... also due to efficiency I need to send filtered data back to php file